# Best practice for informing users of upcoming features

Tags: features, beta

We are currently in the private beta stage of an Agile project delivering an internally facing information application for a client. This is a replacement for a much older legacy system which is feature rich, but has a multitude of UX problems.

In the run up to private beta we put a huge amount of effort into our comms to try and ensure that users understood the Agile process and concepts such as MVP (at a very high level). This was to ensure they didn't think that we were taking things away, just releasing them incrementally.

However due to a muddled comms structure within the organisation we have perhaps not had the penetration we would have liked.

As a result we frequently get users who give feedback asking for features which are still in development. This is to be expected of course as to them all they see is that something isn't there that they used to have.

However I would like to know if anyone has any experience of informing users of upcoming features and how they went about this ? Obviously there are issues about making a rod for your own back by being too specific for example and i'm sure there are others !

I've seen lots of information on 'New features' but not necessarily 'Upcoming ones'.

Comment: Some useful ideas here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93152/is-it-better-to-hide-upcoming-core-features-or-display-coming-soon-text

Comment: Adobe does this with Adobe Xd. Check it here: https://adobexd.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 1):

The best experience I've had for managing expectations in beta phase was with Adobe Xd and their online forum / support. You can not only check if features have already been requested by other users, but you can also vote for the ones you really want.
When they released a feature I had voted for, I received a specific email informing me of the new feature.
Here is their platform: https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests

Answer (score 0):

This happens to my current project as well. My way is to create a roadmap about implemented, implementing & upcoming features. They are sorted by priority. The roadmap is shared with Beta Users, among them are stackholders.

I also created a shared GoogleSheet for them to add user stories that are important to them, but haven't been included in the roadmap. Then after several Sprints, I'll review the updated items on the GoogleSheet and bring them up to the Backlog Grooming meeting later on. Sometimes, items are moved from the Sheet to the very top positions on Backlog list.

This makes everyone happy since they have the feeling like they're involved in the process of app development and their ideas also matter to us :)

P/s: Since I'm a Business Analyst, I smell the rat that the problem may be more complex because of stakeholder conflicts that make consensus can't be reached. But I hope my answer can help you somehow. Cheers!